# How can I get the folder path using FileSystemObject object in JScript?

Tags: javascript, directory, activexobject

What I tried:

```
function getCurrentPath(){
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    return fso.GetFolder(".").Path;
}
```

This code is in a HTML file. Now I want to get the folder path the HTML is in.

But it always return the desktop path.

Comment: ActiveX runs on the client and the html is on the server normally, Is your setup different?

Comment: What is the meaning by my setup different?

Comment: You can run ActiveX on the server, but it is normally run on the client. The html is sent by the server and is rendered by the browser. The actual html is not stored locally (ish - not 100% sure how the browser caches it). The javascript instructs the locally installed ActiveX to access the local (client) file system.

Comment: I know that the name of the activeX which accesses file system,it is FileSystemObject,but I am not sure how to use it .Obviously code above did not work as I expect ,it just return the desktop path such as "C:\user\desktop";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following code:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("scripting.FileSystemObject");
return fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".");
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I get it